# magento deploy:mode:set production fails with MAMP PRO

Tags: magento2

I'm running a development installation on MAMP PRO and when I'm trying to `deploy:mode:set production` it fails at setup:static-content:deploy. When running `setup:static-content:deploy` directly from CLI it succeeds without problems.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

[Stack trace on GitHub.](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3644)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

I found that I had to change the MAMP php.ini file directly, rather than the template.

When I ran `php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;”` from within the root I wasn't seeing the memory limit that I changed in the MAMP template for the version of php I was using.

But when I went to **Applications > MAMP > bin > php > [PHP VERSION] > conf > php.ini** and edited the file there and ran `php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;”` again I was seeing the correct value.

Once I did that compilation worked and I was able to get Production mode set.